# What is the best way to parameterize a pytest function using a fixture that returns a list?

Tags: python, pytest

Right now I have a test file that looks like this contrived example:

```
import pytest

def colors():
    # Expensive operation
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('color', colors())
def test_colors(color):
    assert color != 'mauve'
```

This works fine, but since `colors()` is an expensive operation, I'd like to take advantage of pytest's caching and make it a session scoped fixture. Furthermore, I'd also like to write other tests using it as a fixture like

```
def test_colors_list(colors):
    assert len(colors) == 3
```

Ideally, my test file would look something like

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def colors():
    # Expensive operation
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('color', colors)
def test_colors(color):
    assert color != 'mauve'

def test_colors_list(colors):
    assert len(colors) == 3
```

But this results in an error so I'm not going about this correctly.

Ideally, I would also like to reference other fixtures in `colors()`, as well as still parameterize `test_colors()` to generate multiple functions.

What's the best way I should write these tests?

Comment: Your code (the bottom example) works without error on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6

Comment: Sorry, the actual error I was getting is `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: And it is a `SyntaxError` in my actual project where the fixtures exist in `conftest.py`

Comment: What about `colors()` is expensive? Is calculating all color values expensive?

Comment: Remind me to read your actual code before answering your questions here next time ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to generate the colors in a separate function and use its result as the `params` parameter for a fixture, which you can then use multiple times

```
import pytest

def colors():
    print('expensive')
    return ['blue', 'red', 'mauve']

@pytest.fixture(params=colors())
def color(request):
    return request.param

def test_bla(color):
    print(color, end='')

def test_foo(color):
    print(color, end='')
```

If you run `pytest -s` you will see the string `expensive` only once in the output:

```
$py.test -sv
======================== test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /home/nils/test/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/nils/test/bla, inifile:
collecting 0 items                                                   expensive
collected 6 items

test_bla.py::test_bla[blue] bluePASSED
test_bla.py::test_bla[red] redPASSED
test_bla.py::test_bla[mauve] mauvePASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[blue] bluePASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[red] redPASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[mauve] mauvePASSED

====================== 6 passed in 0.04 seconds ======================
```

However, the expensive function is run at import time, which is not a good behaviour.

Comment: if you use ` --setup-show` it shows that the color fixture is setup and teardown for each test

Comment: Does that matter? The expensive function `colors()` is only executed once, and the returned values are reused.

Comment: If colors() is only executed once, then that's sufficient for my needs. Thanks, I will upvote this since it answers my question best. However, I had hoped to use `colors()` as a fixture because in my actual use case I'd also like to reference other fixtures in it. Is there a way to reference other fixtures within separate helper methods? If not, I'll use your approach and  then reference the fixture within the `color()` fixture instead.

Comment: you are right, @NilsWerner but notice that this way you are not testing the second case ```test_colors_list(colors):``` that's why the ```colors()``` function is executed only once

Comment: Also check my [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119568/636626), which doesn't run the expensive function on import time.

Comment: How would you change it if the function colors took arguments? it does not seem possible to pass arguments like
`params=colors(arg)`

Answer (score 2):

As a work around a simple caching of the result of `colors()` works for the session scope:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def colors():
    try:
        return colors._res
    except AttributeError:
        # Expensive operation
        print()
        print('expensive')
        colors._res = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']
        return colors._res

@pytest.mark.parametrize('color', colors())
def test_colors(color):
    assert color != 'mauve'

def test_colors_list(colors):
    assert len(colors) == 3
```

While the function `colors()` is called twice in it, the expensive calculation is done only once for all tests:

```
$ pytest -sv test_colors.py 
================================================= test session starts ==================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /Users/mike/miniconda3/envs/py36/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/mike/tmp, inifile:
plugins: click-0.1, cov-2.4.0, mock-1.6.0, pylint-0.7.1, xdist-1.15.0, xonsh-0.5.8
collecting 0 items
expensive
collected 4 items 

test_colors.py::test_colors[red] PASSED
test_colors.py::test_colors[yellow] PASSED
test_colors.py::test_colors[blue] PASSED
test_colors.py::test_colors_list PASSED
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to generate the colors in a session fixture and iterate over the returned result in a regular fixture, which you can then use multiple times

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def a():
    return 'purple'

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def colors(a):
    print('expensive')
    return ['blue', 'red', 'mauve', a]

@pytest.fixture(params=range(4))   # unfortunately we need to know the number of values returned by `colors()`
def color(request, colors):
    return colors[request.param]

def test_bla(color):
    print(color, end='')

def test_foo(color):
    print(color, end='')
```

If you run `pytest -s` you will see the string `expensive` only once in the output:

```
$ py.test  -sv
======================== test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3, pytest-3.4.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- cwd
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: cwd, inifile:
collected 8 items

test_bla.py::test_bla[0] expensive
bluePASSED
test_bla.py::test_bla[1] redPASSED
test_bla.py::test_bla[2] mauvePASSED
test_bla.py::test_bla[3] purplePASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[0] bluePASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[1] redPASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[2] mauvePASSED
test_bla.py::test_foo[3] purplePASSED

====================== 8 passed in 0.03 seconds ======================
```

Plus: the expensive function is not called on import time (see where `expensive` appears in the output) and you can use other session fixtures in `colors`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error can be solved as follows:

**test_1.py:**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def colors():
    # Expensive operation
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('color',colors())
def test_colors(color):
    assert color != 'mauve'

def test_colors_list(colors):
    assert len(colors) == 3
```

However, running the previous code in pytest with the  `--setup-show` option that shows the fixture setup and teardown details will show you the following:

```
test_1.py::test_colors[red]
      SETUP    F color[red]
        test_1.py::test_colors[red] (fixtures used: color)PASSED
      TEARDOWN F color[red]
test_1.py::test_colors[yellow]
      SETUP    F color[yellow]
        test_1.py::test_colors[yellow] (fixtures used: color)PASSED
      TEARDOWN F color[yellow]
test_1.py::test_colors[blue]
      SETUP    F color[blue]
        test_1.py::test_colors[blue] (fixtures used: color)PASSED
      TEARDOWN F color[blue]
test_1.py::test_colors_list
SETUP    S colors
        test_1.py::test_colors_list (fixtures used: colors)PASSED
TEARDOWN S colors
```

As you can see in the output the color fixture is setup/teardown for each test case and the colors fixture is setup/teardown once more for the final test case.

To avoid that you can refactor your code minimally as follows:

**test_1.py:**

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def colors():
    # Expensive operation
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue']

def test_colors(colors):
    for color in colors:
        assert color != 'mauve'

def test_colors_list(colors):
    assert len(colors) == 3
```

Running again pytest with `--setup-show` will output the following:

```
test_1.py::test_colors
SETUP    S colors
        test_1.py::test_colors (fixtures used: colors)PASSED
test_1.py::test_colors_list
        test_1.py::test_colors_list (fixtures used: colors)PASSED
TEARDOWN S colors
```

where you can check that the fixture is only setup/teardown once for all tests.

You can take a look a the relevant section in [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I would really like for test_colors to generate multiple test cases rather than exist as one test case with multiple assertions. The un-refactored test_1.py is the behavior I want, but it has the same problem I already have with calling colors() multiple times.